# how to handle the subscribe channel in redis using pub/sub system directly

Tags: redis

Now I want to using redis to implement a pub/sub system, I have 1000+ rss channel in my system. And a scrapy rss channel update app write by Python 3. The 10000+ users to subscribe the channel they like.

When get the article, in the scrapy side, I just want to send the article to channel in redis, and now I store users subscribed articles list in redis like this:

```
cruise:user:1234:subscrible     1,2,3(article id list data structure.....)
```

Now I want when send article to channel, the article id would automatic push into the user subscribe list header. Is it possible to implement in redis?

Now I just know consumer the article on the client side, and find users who subcribe the channel, and using lpush to insert the article id into redis. But the problem is:

when a channel has 10000000 users subscribe, the should invoke lpush command for 10000000+ times. any better sulution? is it possible using redis to maintain the sub/pub relationship and automatic pend article id by redis itself?

[image]

like this model, but the client is a list in redis, I want channel send article id into the client list header.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need binding user to articles. Just binding user to channel, then binding channel to articles.
When get a new article, first, assure and find the channel, then put article id in related channel article list.

Comment: I want to fetch the user subscribe article list in the UI. so I store the user subscribe article ids as a list in redis @Renshaw

Comment: To fetch the user subscribe article list. You can split to 3 steps.  1. get all user subscribe channels. 2. get all articles of each channel. 3. combine all articles